# Mistake in aliyah on Rosh Chodesh

Tags: halacha, mistakes, torah-reading, rosh-chodesh-new-month

On Rosh Chodesh we have four aliyos by Krias HaTorah.

Rosh Chodesh fell out on Monday and by mistake it was read by the first aliyah of Kohen the Parsha of that week. After the aliyah was finished the tzibbur realized this. What should be done now. Should they read only 3 more aliyos with the Kriah of Rosh Chodesh (and divide it appropriately -- thus will come out with 4 aliyos) Or should they read 4 more aliyos with the Kriah of Rosh Chodesh (and come out as having 5 aliyos.) Please provide sources.

Answer (score 2):

According to what it says in SA at the end Siman 685 that by Rosh Chodesh that falls out on Chanukah and you started to read the part for Chanukah (instead of Rosh Chodesh) you must interrupt and go to Rosh Chodesh (see Mishnah Berurah & Bi'ur Halacha), all the more so on a regular Monday. As far as 4 or 5 Aliyot, it has to be a total of 4 because it is not permissible to have more than 4 Alitot on RC. (Only in the extenuating circumstance mentioned in Mishna Berurah 685:15.)